# Android, admob advert is not displaying

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a banner advert in my Android application. I have used Gradle to download the dependencies, etc.

In my activity where I want the advert to be displayed I have:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_mob_id" />
```

And ad_mob_id is

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

Which is for test ads, I took that from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#step_1_modify_the_main_activity_layout

However when I run the activity nothing is displayed and there are no errors/warnings generated.

Am I missing another step?

Comment: @Elltz it is a key publically available on the link I provided. It is not mine

Comment: yeah i just figured that out, Sorry Sir.. apologies

Comment: to tackle your problem, Slr, if you study the logcat, what response does the add give you, in terms of displaying it..

Comment: Nothing. The only steps I have done are adding the above XML to a layout file and adding an entry in my strings.xml, I think I am missing something?

Comment: yes you are Sir, but i thought you were following the tutorial?, you need to load it sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView); // locate the id the banner view
// if you do not use fragments and you are using it directing the remove the getView();
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest); // load it..that's all and you will see logs on it
```

i took it from the link you posted, it has all you need.

Comment: Thanks, LogCat output my device id, so I can now change my ad_mob_id to my one for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes Sir, but also don't forget to add `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` in your `AdRequest` to identify that you are just testing..@andrewb

Comment: Sure, I am using an actual device not the emulator, I have the device id, thank you Sir

Comment: One last comment, my device id is included in the addTestDevice, but I am wondering is that why the banner is an image with text "350x50 test banner" or is that what the users will see too?

Comment: no Sir, the banner has view sizes and that is what you specified in `ads:adSize="BANNER"` in your xml, you can change it and target a higher dimenision, all in the tutorial page but the view sizes is listed [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner#banner_size) , i hope i am not cheecky.. Sir. and also yea the users will see what you will see, when you are testing,in terms of the bannerview @andrewb

Comment: No, I am not talking about the size of the banner, the size is thing. The actual banner has text on it that says "320x50 Test Banner" but I am wondering why they served that banner? It is not advertising anything

Comment: oh yea sorry, NO, yes,yes its because you are using the `.addTestDevice(id)` real addz - advertisers addz will show.. when you remove that line..@andrewb